# GPS gives weird characters when powering my ATMEGA328 on and off?

Tags: arduino, power, atmega, gps, isp

i got a problem with my GPS controlled by ATmega328, when i download the code using arduino ISP the GPS works fine and the lcd displays correct data, but when i remove the power from the atmega328 and connect it again the GPS starts to send weird data to the lcd.
the two pictures below illustrates my problem :
[image]

[image]

```
      #include "ALCD.H"
      char rowCount;
      char lastPOSy;
      void lcd_reset()
      {
      lcd_port_dir=0XFF;
      lcd_port = 0xFF;
      _delay_ms(20);
      lcd_port = 0x03+LCD_EN;
      lcd_port = 0x03;
      _delay_ms(10);
      lcd_port = 0x03+LCD_EN;
      lcd_port = 0x03;
      _delay_ms(1);
      lcd_port = 0x03+LCD_EN;
      lcd_port = 0x03;
      _delay_ms(1);
      lcd_port = 0x02+LCD_EN;
     lcd_port = 0x02;
     _delay_ms(1);
    }

     void lcd_init (unsigned char rows)
     {
     rowCount=rows;
     lastPOSy=0;
    lcd_reset();         // Call LCD reset
    lcd_cmd(0x28);       // 4-bit mode - 2 line - 5x7 font. 
    lcd_cmd(0x0c);       // Display no cursor - no blink.
    lcd_cmd(0x06);       // Automatic Increment - No Display shift.
    lcd_cmd(0x80);       // Address DDRAM with 0 offset 80h.
     }

   void lcd_cmd (char cmd)
    {
    lcd_port = ((cmd >> 4) & 0x0F)|LCD_EN;
    lcd_port = ((cmd >> 4) & 0x0F);

    lcd_port = (cmd & 0x0F)|LCD_EN;
    lcd_port = (cmd & 0x0F);

    _delay_us(200);
    _delay_us(200);
     }

   void lcd_data (unsigned char dat)
   {
    lcd_port = (((dat >> 4) & 0x0F)|LCD_EN|LCD_RS);
    lcd_port = (((dat >> 4) & 0x0F)|LCD_RS);

    lcd_port = ((dat & 0x0F)|LCD_EN|LCD_RS);
    lcd_port = ((dat & 0x0F)|LCD_RS);

    _delay_us(200);
    _delay_us(200);
    }
    void lcd_gotoxy(char posX,char posY)
 {
 if (posY==0 ) 
    lcd_cmd((1<<7)+0x00+posX);
  else
  {
    lcd_cmd((1<<7)+0x40+posX);
  lastPOSy=1;
   }        
    _delay_us(40);
  }

 void lcd_clear(void)
 {
lcd_cmd(0x01);
_delay_ms(2);
lcd_cmd(0x02);
_delay_ms(2);
}

 void lcd_putchar(unsigned char data)
 {
 lcd_data(data);
 }

void lcd_puts( char *str)
{
unsigned char i=0;

while(*(str+i)!='\0'&&i<rowCount)
{
lcd_data(str[i]);
i++;    
}
if (i>rowCount-1&&lastPOSy==0)
{
    i=rowCount;
    lcd_gotoxy(0,1);

while(*(str+i)!='\0')
{
lcd_data(str[i]);
i++;    
}
}

}

void lcd_putconsts(const char *str)
{
unsigned char i=0;

while(*(str+i)!='\0'&&i<rowCount)
{
lcd_data(str[i]);
i++;    
}
if (i>rowCount-1&&lastPOSy==0)
{
    i=rowCount;
    lcd_gotoxy(0,1);

while(*(str+i)!='\0')
{
lcd_data(str[i]);
i++;    
}
}
}
```

Comment: does it stay like that forever?

Comment: Is the USB the only thing powering the entire circuit (ATmega/GPS/LCD)? It looks like your character signals to the LCD are going out of sync, or some setting is changing. Do you have a reset button affecting all devices? Have you tried debugging the code within the ATmega to see if it is sending correct data to the LCD?

Comment: @KyranF : yes it stay like that forever, unless i downloaded the code again via the ISP.

Comment: @Mewa :yes the USB from the arduino is the only thing powering my circuit and i don't have any reset button. i didn't try debugging but its already sending correct data as seen in the first pic.

Comment: How long is the delay in code between starting up the Arduino, initializing the LCD, initializing the GPS module and beginning to interface with the LCD?

Comment: Are you running the LCD in 4 bit mode or 8 bit mode?

Comment: @Mewa : there is no delay actually, does it matter ?

Comment: @alex.forencich : 4 bit mode

Comment: Hm, that LCD module is pretty slow in general (I mean, compared to other screens out there). It has a built-in initialization routine that lasts something like 10 ms once power is applied. I'm wondering if the ISP holds it in reset long enough after power up to let this complete, but when you plug in the USB, this does not happen. Try adding a delay after power-up before you initialize the LCD and see if that changes things.

Comment: @Mewa : i tried adding delay before lcd initialization and after and both cases didn't work

Comment: :( How much of a delay did you try?

Comment: @Mewa :1000 msec

Comment: Odd. Could you post your initialization code for the LCD? In my experience with these things, problems are usually caused by improper initialization delays. Hopefully some breadboard people will show up and give some insight on power as well :)

Comment: @Mewa : i have updated the problem with lcd initialization code

Comment: maybe part of the init routine should be to power-cycle it somehow? On your breadboard, if you have a spare DIO pin on the controller, use that to switch on/off power to the LCD display using a transistor (a logic-level MOSFET, P channel)

Comment: Could you add your lcd_cmd function code as well? The screen goes into 8-bit mode on reset, maybe it just does not receive the 4-bit mode command correctly. Keep in mind that the 0x2 to set 4-bit mode needs to be sent once, but all commands after that (display on, clear, etc) have to be sent as two nibbles.

Comment: @KyranF : I have tried a simple code and write Hello to the lcd and powerd off the circuit and then powered it on again and there was no problem. the problem isn't with the lcd i think.

Comment: perhaps there is a setting which is set too fast on power-up? Not sure, sorry.

Comment: If you are switching the LCD to 4-bit mode, then what's probably happening is that the nibbles get out of sync the 2nd time you initialize it.  The HD44780 command set is rather crappy as this sort of thing is possible.  The only recourse is to reset the LCD by power cycling it.

Comment: How are these devices connected?
Is the GPS somehow sending after re-set?
If not, the problem will be with the LCD.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by running the init routine switch the LCD from 8 bit mode to 4 bit mode when it is already in 4 bit mode.  It may be possible to try putting it in 8 bit mode and then switching back to 4 bit mode.  The most reliable solution is probably just power cycling the display as part of the init routine get it in a consistent state.